# Append integer to beginning of list in Python

Tags: python, list, prepend

How do I prepend an integer to the beginning of a list?

```
[1, 2, 3]  ⟶  [42, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: in terms of computation time, is `new_list = [x] + your_list` less efficient than `your_list.insert(x)`?

Answer (score 1265, accepted):

```
>>> x = 42
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3]
>>> xs.insert(0, x)
>>> xs
[42, 1, 2, 3]
```

How it works:

`list.insert(index, value)`

Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so `xs.insert(0, x)` inserts at the front of the list, and `xs.insert(len(xs), x)` is equivalent to `xs.append(x)`. Negative values are treated as being relative to the end of the list.

Comment: The most efficient approach. Faster than [x]+[y]. See solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537916/whats-the-idiomatic-syntax-for-prepending-to-a-short-python-list

Comment: @BlackJack The question is about how to append integer to beginning of list. Whatever he describe that is not the right thing to follow. So why to guide him to take the wrong path? when there are better thing he can do for his requirement.

Comment: In that case question title should be different. Anyway there is no point of arguing, as the point is clear for both of us. Anyway thank you for pointing out.  :)

Comment: use append(), then reverse() function, as insert(0,val) function will take more time,because it will involve shifting of every element.
i have experienced a time out issue due to insert

Comment: @VishalYadav Can you please share the benchmarking?

Comment: @Nullify , for example appending and reversing of 10000000 elements took almost 1.2 seconds which is equal to inserting 100 elements at 0th postion of a list.Below is the code to test,

link will expire in a day , have a look 
https://ctxt.io/2/AACgpeUnFg

Comment: in terms of computation time, is `new_list = [x] + your_list` less efficient than `your_list.insert(x)`?

Answer (score 604):

```
>>> x = 42
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [x] + xs
[42, 1, 2, 3]
```

Note: don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: I just did some benchmarking. `li.insert(0, a)` is around 5x faster than `li = [a] + li`. Keep this in mind if you are doing this many times.

Comment: @MarcelPfeiffer It should be noted that `li.insert(0, a)` is mutating `li`. `li = [a] + li` is creating a new instance will all of the values. This is an important distinction if other things have a reference to the list instance.

Comment: It would be nice for python to add a list.push_front(item) function. This will be obvious and less error-prone.

Comment: @KeminZhou I'd prefer the name "prepend" as it follows naturally from "append" as "push_front" follows naturally from "push_back".

Comment: @god of llamas, I agree with you.  Shorter is always better.

Comment: @Marcel Pfeiffer `collections.deque.appendleft()` should be even faster for large len(li).

Comment: @MarcelPfeiffer but that's not as pythonic!

Comment: Answer from @timgeb below makes sense esp. if there are too many inserts at front of list.

Comment: in terms of computation time, is `new_list = [x] + your_list` less efficient than `your_list.insert(x)`?

Answer (score 134):

Note that if you are trying to do that operation often, especially in loops, **a list is the wrong data structure**.

Lists are not optimized for modifications at the front, and `somelist.insert(0, something)` is an [O(n) operation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

`somelist.pop(0)` and `del somelist[0]` are also O(n) operations.

The correct data structure to use is a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) from the `collections` module. deques expose an interface that is similar to those of lists, but are optimized for modifications from both endpoints. They have an `appendleft` method for insertions at the front.

Demo:

```
In [1]: lst = [0]*1000
In [2]: timeit -n1000 lst.insert(0, 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 794 ns per loop
In [3]: from collections import deque
In [4]: deq = deque([0]*1000)
In [5]: timeit -n1000 deq.appendleft(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 73 ns per loop
```

Comment: Sometimes switching structures isn't a thing you can do easily, and if you need to append a bunch of stuff to the front, you can call .reverse then add all the stuff to the end, then call reverse again. You'd get two O(n) operations but then use the O(1) adds of list.

Comment: in terms of computation time, is `new_list = [x] + your_list` less efficient than `your_list.insert(x)`?

Comment: That's not the question though. Keep in mind, sometimes you didn't create the list and it came from some other team/library where you'd like to append in the front. There are times when you have no control over externalities. :-)

Answer (score 55):

Another way of doing the same,

```
list[0:0] = [a]
```

Comment: You don't need the first 0. The colon already say that's before the start -- my_list[:0]=[a] does it.

Comment: Elegant solution!

Comment: This is interesting to know about, but I would avoid this because I think it might cause confusion.

Comment: This is not elegant, it's unnecessarily confusing and difficult to read.

Answer (score 24):

You can use Unpack list:

> a = 5
>
> li = [1,2,3]
>
> li = [a, *li]
>
> => *[5, 1, 2, 3]*

Answer (score 12):

Based on some (minimal) benchmarks using the `timeit` module it seems that the following has similar if not better performance than the accepted answer

```
new_lst = [a, *lst]
```

As with `[a] + list` this will create a new list and not mutate `lst`.

If your intention is to mutate the list then use `lst.insert(0, a)`.

Answer (score 11):

```
list_1.insert(0,ur_data)
```

make sure that ur_data is of string type
so if u have `data= int(5)` convert it to `ur_data = str(data)`

Answer (score 6):

### Alternative Solution:

```py
>>> from collections import deque

>>> my_list = deque()
>>> my_list.append(1)       # append right
>>> my_list.append(2)       # append right
>>> my_list.append(3)       # append right
>>> my_list.appendleft(100) # append left
>>> my_list

deque([100, 1, 2, 3])

>>> my_list[0]

100
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

`collections.deque` is faster than Python pure `list` in a loop <sup>[Relevant-Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23487658/3702377)</sup>.

Comment: Thank you so much. This made me pass my codeforces problem

Answer (score 2):

None of these worked for me. I converted the first element to be part of a series (a single element series), and converted the second element also to be a series, and used append function.

```
l = ((pd.Series(<first element>)).append(pd.Series(<list of other elements>))).tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

New lists can be made by simply adding lists together.

```
list1 = ['value1','value2','value3']
list2 = ['value0']
newlist=list2+list1
print(newlist)
```

Comment: This is already covered by the top rated answer. Please explain how this adds new information to the issue.

Comment: O, it adds nothing