# python: deque vs list performance comparison

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, benchmarking, deque

In python docs I can see that deque is a special collection highly optimized for poping/adding items from left or right sides. E.g. documentation says:

> Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is
>   pronounced “deck” and is short for “double-ended queue”). Deques
>   support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either
>   side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in
>   either direction.
>
> Though list objects support similar operations, they are optimized for
>   fast fixed-length operations and incur O(n) memory movement costs for
>   pop(0) and insert(0, v) operations which change both the size and
>   position of the underlying data representation.

I decided to make some comparisons using *ipython*. Could anyone explain me what I did wrong here:

```
In [31]: %timeit range(1, 10000).pop(0)
 10000 loops, best of 3: 114 us per loop

In [32]: %timeit deque(xrange(1, 10000)).pop() 
10000 loops, best of 3: 181 us per loop

In [33]: %timeit deque(range(1, 10000)).pop()
1000 loops, best of 3: 243 us per loop
```

Comment: It takes O(n) time to create a `deque` object from a list (such as `range` or `xrange`).

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Agree with @JayanthKoushik, time `.pop` after both list and deque created.

Comment: deque has internal locks to achieve **thread safe**, but list doesn't.

Comment: @XingFei No, collections.deque doesn't have internal locks. For that you want Queue.Queue. But the append(), appendleft(), pop(), popleft() and len() methods of deque can be considered atomic not by guarantee of contract, but by how they're implemented in CPython. See https://bugs.python.org/issue15329#msg199368

(For example, iterating over a deque is not thread-safe).

Comment: @Michael Ruth - The fact that the questions uses one Python2 feature doesn't make the answers and the general question irrelevant to [python] in general.  I re-added that tag so people can find it.  I'm not a Python expert, but I assume most of the answers *are* relevant to Python in general.

Answer (score 146):

`Could anyone explain me what I did wrong here`

Yes, your timing is dominated by the time to create the list or deque.  The time to do the *pop* is insignificant in comparison.

Instead you should isolate the thing you're trying to test (the pop speed) from the setup time:

```
In [1]: from collections import deque

In [2]: s = list(range(1000))

In [3]: d = deque(s)

In [4]: s_append, s_pop = s.append, s.pop

In [5]: d_append, d_pop = d.append, d.pop

In [6]: %timeit s_pop(); s_append(None)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 115 ns per loop

In [7]: %timeit d_pop(); d_append(None)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 70.5 ns per loop
```

That said, the real differences between deques and list in terms of performance are:

- Deques have O(1) speed for *appendleft()* and *popleft()* while lists have O(n) performance for *insert(0, value)* and *pop(0)*.
- List append performance is hit and miss because it uses *realloc()* under the hood.  As a result, it tends to have over-optimistic timings in simple code (because the realloc doesn't have to move data) and really slow timings in real code (because fragmentation forces realloc to move all the data).  In contrast, deque append performance is consistent because it never reallocs and never moves data.

Comment: Is deque implemented as a linked list? Or how can you guarantee it won't require realloc?

Comment: Yes, it uses linked list logic.  More specifically, it uses a doubly-linked list of fixed length blocks.

Comment: Use of `realloc()` for lists is just an optimization.  The list is over-allocated each time it is resized to guarantee O(1) amortized append performance, even if the data has to be copied on each resize.

Comment: @augurar The use of *realloc()* isn't an optimization, it is at the core of how lists grow.  It is the overallocation strategy that is the optimization -- that strategy reduces the number of calls to *realloc()* but it does not eliminate them. *realloc()* is still called periodically. This makes timings less repeatable and harder to interpret because the realloc performance varies wildly depending on whether the data has to be copied.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger The algorithm used in [dynamic arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) does not depend on the existence of the `realloc()` Unix syscall, it's just a practical optimization to avoid copying when possible.  Even if the data has to be copied every time the array is resized, the algorithm still achieves [amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) `O(1)` insertion performance.

Comment: @augurar You're missing the point completely.  Yes, there is amortized O(1) performance.  However, the constant factor varies wildly because the underlying operation is sometimes cheap and sometimes expensive.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger do you mean `s = list(range(1000))` as `'range' object has no attribute 'append'`?

Comment: @zyxue I'll update the answer.  It was correct for Python 2 where *range()* returned a list.

Answer (score 46):

For what it is worth:

### Python 3

`deque.pop` vs `list.pop`

```py
> python3 -mtimeit -s 'import collections' -s 'items = range(10000000); base = [*items]' -s 'c = collections.deque(base)' 'c.pop()'
5000000 loops, best of 5: 46.5 nsec per loop 
    
> python3 -mtimeit -s 'import collections' -s 'items = range(10000000); base = [*items]' 'base.pop()'
5000000 loops, best of 5: 55.1 nsec per loop
```

`deque.appendleft` vs `list.insert`

```py
> python3 -mtimeit -s 'import collections' -s 'c = collections.deque()' 'c.appendleft(1)'
5000000 loops, best of 5: 52.1 nsec per loop

> python3 -mtimeit -s 'c = []' 'c.insert(0, 1)'
50000 loops, best of 5: 12.1 usec per loop
```

### Python 2

```py
> python -mtimeit -s 'import collections' -s 'c = collections.deque(xrange(1, 100000000))' 'c.pop()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.11 usec per loop
    
> python -mtimeit -s 'c = range(1, 100000000)' 'c.pop()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.174 usec per loop
   
> python -mtimeit -s 'import collections' -s 'c = collections.deque()' 'c.appendleft(1)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.116 usec per loop
    
> python -mtimeit -s 'c = []' 'c.insert(0, 1)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 36.4 usec per loop
```

As you can see, where it really shines is in `appendleft` vs `insert`.

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend you to refer 
https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Python lists and deque have simlilar complexities for most operations(push,pop etc.)

Comment: But critically, *not* for `popleft` / `.pop(0)` / pop intermediate which is what this question was *trying* to measure.

Answer (score 11):

I found my way to this question and thought I'd offer up an example with a little context.
A classic use-case for using a Deque might be rotating/shifting elements in a collection because (as others have mentioned), you get very good (O(1)) complexity for push/pop operations on both ends because these operations are just moving references around as opposed to a list which has to physically move objects around in memory.

So here are 2 *very* similar-looking implementations of a rotate-left function:

```py
def rotate_with_list(items, n):
    l = list(items)
    for _ in range(n):
        l.append(l.pop(0))
    return l

from collections import deque
def rotate_with_deque(items, n):
    d = deque(items)
    for _ in range(n):
        d.append(d.popleft())
    return d
```

> Note: This is such a common use of a deque that the deque has a built-in `rotate` method, but I'm doing it manually here for the sake of visual comparison.

Now let's `%timeit`.

```
In [1]: def rotate_with_list(items, n):
   ...:     l = list(items)
   ...:     for _ in range(n):
   ...:         l.append(l.pop(0))
   ...:     return l
   ...: 
   ...: from collections import deque
   ...: def rotate_with_deque(items, n):
   ...:     d = deque(items)
   ...:     for _ in range(n):
   ...:         d.append(d.popleft())
   ...:     return d
   ...: 

In [2]: items = range(100000)

In [3]: %timeit rotate_with_list(items, 800)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit rotate_with_deque(items, 800)
The slowest run took 5.89 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 527 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit rotate_with_list(items, 8000)
10 loops, best of 3: 174 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit rotate_with_deque(items, 8000)
The slowest run took 8.99 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 ms per loop

In [7]: more_items = range(10000000)

In [8]: %timeit rotate_with_list(more_items, 800)
1 loop, best of 3: 4.59 s per loop

In [9]: %timeit rotate_with_deque(more_items, 800)
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop
```

Pretty interesting how both data structures expose an eerily similar interface but have drastically different performance :)

Answer (score 1):

out of curiosity I tried inserting in beginning in list vs appendleft() of deque.
clearly deque is winner.
[image]

Comment: It's better to copy/paste code and text as text (with code blocks for formatting), not pictures of text, like how sberry showed results in their answer.  Some users are blind and use text-to-speech, and others are behind corporate firewalls the block imgur.

Comment: @PeterCordes it's hardly 7 lines.

Comment: Then it shouldn't take long to copy/paste and format.

Comment: This code can't be run on pure Python anyway, @PeterCordes. The criticism is a little too nitpicky in my opinion. Want something that you can copy/paste, use another answer; cause it makes no sense to copy/paste this in any scenario.

Comment: @CanH.Tartanoglu: I never said *I wanted* to copy/paste this code anywhere, I said that's what the author of this answer should do, from their code into SO.  It's about searches indexing text not images.  And the reasons I mentioned in my first comment: blind users, and firewalls that block imgur.

Comment: The response being discussed has a flavour that I appreciate seeing, and sadly it just doesn't make sense to copy/paste the code. Yes, it is not an inclusive format, and that is a problem. There is a direct equivalent that can be copy/pasted in other answers.

We should advocate for jupyter notebook integration into the StackExchange framework, because this puts way too much pressure on responders using native features.