# Does a list have any advantages over a deque in Python?

Tags: python

Deques can perform certain operations faster than lists can; can lists do anything faster? Do they have any advantages at all?

Comment: If you Google "python list deque" you'll find lots of relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Deques are faster adding/removing elements to the end or beginning.

Lists are faster adding/removing elements to any other 'middle' position.

You can also use insert(index, value) on lists, while on deques you can only append left or right.

You have a more detailed thread here: [deque vs list performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487307/python-deque-vs-list-performance-comparison)

Comment: Deques are faster adding/removing elements at the beginning only. You can use insert(index, value) on deques.