# Should I use a Python deque or list as a stack?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, data-structures

I want a Python object that I can use as a stack. Is it better to use a deque or a list and does it make a difference whether I have a small number of elements or a large number of elements?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your mileage may vary according to your application and precise use case, but in the general case, a list is well suited for a stack:

`append` is O(1)

`pop()` is O(1) - as long as you do not pop from an arbitrary position; `pop()` only from the end.

Deques are also O(1) for these operations, but require importing a module from the standard library, require 'O(n)' for random access. An argument could be made to prefer using vanilla lists though, unless for specific applicatins.

#### Correction:

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487307/python-deque-vs-list-performance-comparison) by Raymond Hettinger, a principal author of the C code for both list and deque, it appears that deques may perform slightly better than lists: The pop() operation of deques seem to have the advantage.

```
In [1]: from collections import deque

In [2]: s = list(range(1000))      # range(1000) if python 2

In [3]: d = deque(s)

In [4]: s_append, s_pop = s.append, s.pop

In [5]: d_append, d_pop = d.append, d.pop

In [6]: %timeit s_pop(); s_append(None)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 115 ns per loop

In [7]: %timeit d_pop(); d_append(None)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 70.5 ns per loop
```

> the real differences between deques and list in terms of performance
> are:
>
> Deques have O(1) speed for appendleft() and popleft() while lists have
> O(n) performance for insert(0, value) and pop(0).
> List append
> performance is hit and miss because it uses realloc() under the hood.
> As a result, it tends to have over-optimistic timings in simple code
> (because the realloc doesn't have to move data) and really slow
> timings in real code (because fragmentation forces realloc to move all
> the data). In contrast, deque append performance is consistent because
> it never reallocs and never moves data.

Comment: If you’re going to contrast two solutions, why emphasize the part where they’re the same? They’re not “arguably” O(1) with a deque – they *are* O(1). And what’s the supposed overhead? Got any benchmarks to back that up?

Comment: I stand corrected regarding performance @Ryan - I posted an erratum.

Comment: Note that the quoted post was made by Python core developer, Raymond Hettinger, a principal author of the C code for both [`list`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/listobject.c) and [`deque`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L10), so he knows what he's talking about!

Comment: I get: `AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: I have updated the answer @EduardoPignatelli, it was correct in python 2, when `range` returned a `list`.