# Making code that is both iterative and recursive purely iterative

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I have huge lists (>1,000,000 in most cases) that are partitioned into `n x n` grids. These lists are of some coordinates. I define a neighbouring relation between points - if they are within range of each other, they are 'neighbours' and put into a 'cluster'. We can add cells to these clusters, so cell A is a neighbour of cell B, B a neighbour of C, C is **not** a neighbour of A. A, B, and C would be in the same cluster.

Given that background, I have the following code that tries to assign points to clusters in Python 3.6:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        tile = image[i][j]
        while tile:
            cell = tile.pop()
            cluster = create_and_return_cluster(cell, image_clusters[i][j], (i, j))
            clusterise(cell, cluster, (i, j), image, n, windows, image_clusters)

def clusterise(cell, cluster, tile_index, image, n, windows, image_clusters):
    neighbouring_windows, neighbouring_indices = get_neighbouring_windows(tile_index[0], tile_index[1], n, windows)
    neighbours = get_and_remove_all_neighbours(cell, image, tile_index, neighbouring_windows, neighbouring_indices)
    if neighbours:
        for neighbour, (n_i, n_j) in neighbours:
            add_to_current_cluster(cluster, image_clusters, neighbour, (n_j, n_j))
            clusterise(neighbour, cluster, (n_i, n_j), image, n, windows, image_clusters)
```

Because of the massive size of the lists, I've had issues with RecursionError and have been scouring the internet for suggestions on tail-recursion. The problem is that this algorithm needs to branch from neighbours to pick up neighbours of **those** neighbours, and so on. As you can imagine, this gets pretty big pretty quickly in terms of stack frames.

My question is: is it possible to make this algorithm use tail-recursion, or how would one go about making it tail-recursive? I know the `cluster` argument is essentially an accumulator in this case, but given how the lists shrink and the nasty for-loop in `clusterise()` I am not sure how to successfully convert to tail-recursion. Does anyone have any ideas? Ideally supported with an explanation.

NB: I am well aware that Python does not optimise tail-recursion by default, yes I am aware that other languages optimise tail-recursion. My question is whether it can be done in this case using Python. I don't want to change if I don't absolutely have to and much of my other code is already in Python.

Comment: So use a queue or stack. You don't have tail-recursion here.

Comment: How deep does the recursion go? I don't see an anchor.

Comment: @fafl as deep as the size of the cluster it's on - which is obviously variable. If there are no neighbours, it terminates. Note that due to removal of cells there is no 'competing' from two cells to the same neighbour.

Comment: Tail-recursion is not a language feature. Python supports tail-recursion just fine. What Python *doesn't* do, and some other languages *do*, is **optimise** tail-recursion functions. That's a big difference. See [What Is Tail Call Optimization?](//stackoverflow.com/q/310974) and [Does Python optimize tail recursion?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13591970)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a queue or stack to track which neighbours to process next; the following function does exactly the same work as your recursive function, iteratively:

```
from collections import deque

def clusterise(cell, cluster, tile_index, image, n, windows, image_clusters):
    to_process = deque([(cell, tile_index)])
    while to_process:
        cell, tile_index = to_process.pop()
        neighbouring_windows, neighbouring_indices = get_neighbouring_windows(tile_index[0], tile_index[1], n, windows)
        neighbours = get_and_remove_all_neighbours(cell, image, tile_index, neighbouring_windows, neighbouring_indices)
        if neighbours:
            for neighbour, (n_i, n_j) in neighbours:
                add_to_current_cluster(cluster, image_clusters, neighbour, (n_j, n_j))
                to_process.append((neighbour, (n_i, n_j))
```

So instead of using the Python stack to track what still needs to be processed, we move the varying arguments (`cell` and `tile_index`) to a `deque` stack managed by the function instead, which isn't bound like the Python stack is. You can also use it as a queue (pop from the beginning instead of the end with `to_process.popleft()`) for a breadth-first processing order. Note that your recursive solution process cells depth-first.

As a side note: yes, you can use a regular Python `list` as a stack too, but due to the nature of how a list object is grown and shrunk dynamically, for a *stack* the `deque` linked-list implementation is more efficient. And it's easier to switch between a stack and a queue this way. See [Raymond Hettinger's remarks on deque performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23487658).