# Is inserting to head of a list using slice faster than insert(0,...)?

Tags: python, performance, list, insertion

There are 2 functions.

```
def f1(n):
    t = time()
    m = []
    for i in range(n):
        m.insert(0, 0)
    return time() - t

def f2(n):
    t = time()
    m = []
    for i in range(n):
        m[:0] = [0]
    return time() - t
```

They both insert many elements to list. But the second uses slice. I know that these algorithms are bad(because O(N^2)) but looks like f2 faster than f1(I tried both Python 2 and Python 3).

(You can see time here http://rextester.com/XSPGVO38315)

Is it random or there is a reson for which f2 is better than f1? Are these function equal? If no, what is better(faster)?

Comment: You should use the `timeit` module for benchmarking.

Comment: Better is to not build a list by adding elements to the front in the first place. Append them to the end, and then reverse the list if you really need to.

Comment: consider using `collections.deque` which has better `insert(0, v)` performance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23487307/9209546

Comment: So from the link @Barmar posted, the C implementation for slice seems to be faster, I think because of memmove instead of a loop. On my machine about 1.5X faster for 10k elements.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried with timeit and now time of f1 is almost equal to the time of f2. Thanks.