# Python Prepend a list of dicts

Tags: python

I have this list:

`[('1', '1')]`

and I want to prepend the list with a dict object to look like:

`[('All', 'All'), ('1', '1')]`

I'm trying:

`myList[:0] = dict({'All': 'All'})`

But that gives me:

`['All', ('1', '1')]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't include a dictionary.... You want a `(key, value)` tuple of your dict inserted into the list?

Comment: `dict({'All': 'All'})` is redundant, anyway.

Comment: `myList[:0] = dict({'All': 'All'}).items()` will do this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `items()` of dictionary to get key, value and prepend them to list:

```
lst = [('1', '1')]
lst = list({'All': 'All'}.items()) + lst

print(lst)
# [('All', 'All'), ('1', '1')]
```

*Note*: `{'All': 'All'}` is a dictionary itself, so `dict({'All': 'All'})` in your code is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `dict` in as an iterable, you only iterate over its keys.  If you instead want to iterate over its key/value pairs, you have to use the `dict.items` view.

```
l = [('1', '1')]
d = dict({'All': 'All'})
print([*d.items(), *l])
# [('All', 'All'), ('1', '1')]
```

The `*` syntax is [available in Python 3.5 and later](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

```
l[:0] = d.items()
```

also works

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at below.

```
>>> myList = [('1', '1')]
>>>
>>> myList[:0] = dict({'All': 'All'}).items()
>>> myList
[('All', 'All'), ('1', '1')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For an answer like `[('All', 'All'), ('1', '1')]`, do:

```
myList = [('1', '1')]
myList = [('All', 'All')] + myList
```

For more, reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911091/append-integer-to-beginning-of-list-in-python/17911209).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the function below for appending any dict as list items to already present list. You just have to send a new dict which you want to append with the old list already present with you.

```
    def append_dict_to_list(new_dict,old_list):
        list_to_append = list(new_dict.items())
        new_list = list_to_append + old_list 
        return new_list 

    print (append_dict_to_list({'All':'All'},[('1', '1')]))
```

P.S: If you want the new dict to be appended after the existing list, just change the sequence in code as new_list =  old_list + list_to_append