# How to add leading zeros to a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list which has length 1000. E.g., x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, ..., 1000.0]. I would like to add 4 leading zero to above list. E.g. x_new = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ..., 1000.0]

I don't know how to add leading zeros to list. So, can you guys help me how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating two lists - difference between '+=' and extend()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list concatenation:

```py
x_new = [0.0] * 4 + x
```

or

```py
x_new = [0.0 for _ in range(4)] + x
```

Comment: Or just `[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]+x`

Comment: Or `[*[0.0]*4, *x]`

Comment: In this case there's nothing wrong in doing like suggested by @ScottHunter, but the one described in the answer is a more general case. Anyway it deserves my +1

Answer (score 0):

The answer by `BrokenBenchmark` is valid and working, but I would suggest a more pure solution:

```
x.insert(0, 0.0)
```

This appends a leading `0.0` at the beginning of `x`, you just have to do this 4 times.

This is *more pure* because it edits `x` without creating a new `list` object.

---

I would suggest you to read [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911091/append-integer-to-beginning-of-list-in-python) and [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537916/whats-the-idiomatic-syntax-for-prepending-to-a-short-python-list)

## Edit

---

As `Mechanic Pig` suggested in the comments, this is a very unefficient way of doing this, it's one of the least efficient ways of doing this, I'm suggesting it only because it *"adds leading zeros to a list"*, instead of *"creating a new list concatenating two lists of which the first one has 4 leading zeros".*

Comment: Repeatedly inserting elements in the first position of the list requires constantly moving memory. I don't recommend this usage.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by FLAK-ZOSO is very good, but in case you want to know how to properly iterate you can do this:

```
for i in range(4):
    x.insert(0, 0.0)
```

Yes, this is not the most efficient thing as mentioned by Mechanic Pig, but I think that it's a lot more customizable and easy to understand.