# Appending to range function

Tags: python, python-2.x

**EDIT**: Thank you for your kind replies on how to accomplish what I am trying to do, but the question is about *WHY*  range().append() returns None if you try it in one step, and *WHY* it works if you two-step the procedure.

Im trying to create a numerical list but with a twist. I don't want a couple of  numbers at the beggining of my list:

```
mlist = [0, 5, 6, 7, ...]
```

So i thought to do the following:

```
 mlist = range(5,n+1).append(0)
```

but silently fails because `type(mlist)` afterwards equals to `NoneType` ?! (related: `type(range(5,10)` evaluates to `list` Type)

If i try to do that in two steps eg:

```
>>> mlist = range(5,10)
#and then
>>> mlist.append(0)
>>> mlist
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0]
```

What's happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the idiomatic syntax for prepending to a short python list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537916/whats-the-idiomatic-syntax-for-prepending-to-a-short-python-list)

Comment: I'm a little sceptical of that last snippet.  :^)  You should get an `mlist` of `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]`, and the spacing is wrong.  Please copy and paste transcripts -- it's too easy to make mistakes otherwise.

Comment: @DSM You are correct, I was aiming for a fast example to illustrate that a two-step move works :)

Comment: I did explain *why*; because `.append()` alters the list in place. And that also makes you question a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

`list.append()` alters the list *in place*, and returns `None`. By assigning you assigned that return value to `mlist`, not the list you wanted to build.  This is a standard Python idiom; methods that alter the mutable object never return the altered object, always `None`.

Separate the two steps:

```
mlist = range(5, n + 1)
mlist.append(0)
```

This adds `[0]` to the **end**; if you need the `0` at the start, use:

```
mlist = [0] + range(5, n + 1)
```

or you can use `list.insert()`, again as a separate call:

```
mlist = range(5, n + 1)
mlist.insert(0, 0)
```

but the latter has to shift up all elements one step and creating a new list by concatenation is the faster option for shorter lists, insertion wins on longer lists:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> def concat(n):
...     mlist = [0] + range(5, n)
... 
>>> def insert(n):
...     mlist = range(5, n)
...     mlist.insert(0, 0)
... 
>>> timeit('concat(10)', 'from __main__ import concat')
1.2668070793151855
>>> timeit('insert(10)', 'from __main__ import insert')
1.4820878505706787
>>> timeit('concat(1000)', 'from __main__ import concat')
23.53221583366394
>>> timeit('insert(1000)', 'from __main__ import insert')
15.84601092338562
```

Comment: Why not `insert` to the start?

Comment: Because then you shift all elements up one place; may as well create a new list.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple options, but the simplest one might be:

```
>>> mlist = [0] + range(5,10)
>>> mlist
[0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

To insert an item at the beginning, use [`list.insert`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#mutable-sequence-types) with `0` (index 0):

```
>>> mlist = range(5,10)
>>> mlist.insert(0, 0) # the first 0: index, the second 0: the item to insert
>>> mlist
[0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Answer to EDIT**:

Most methods that change the sequence/maping in place return `None`. So just call the method, and do not reassign the return value to the variable.

See [Why doesn’t list.sort() return the sorted list?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-doesn-t-list-sort-return-the-sorted-list) from the Python FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

> EDIT: Thank you for your kind replies on how to accomplish what I am trying to do, but the question is about WHY range().append() returns None if you try it in one step, and WHY it works if you two-step the procedure.

Put simply - GvR didn't like it - from the [Python developers mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html):

> I'd like to explain once more why I'm so adamant that sort() shouldn't
>   return 'self'.
>
> This comes from a coding style (popular in various other languages, I
>   believe especially Lisp revels in it) where a series of side effects
>   on a single object can be chained like this:
>
> x.compress().chop(y).sort(z)
>
> which would be the same as
>
> x.compress()
>    x.chop(y)
>    x.sort(z)
>
> I find the chaining form a threat to readability; it requires that the
>   reader must be intimately familiar with each of the methods.  The
>   second form makes it clear that each of these calls acts on the same
>   object, and so even if you don't know the class and its methods very
>   well, you can understand that the second and third call are applied to
>   x (and that all calls are made for their side-effects), and not to
>   something else.
>
> I'd like to reserve chaining for operations that return new values,
>   like string processing operations:
>
> y = x.rstrip("\n").split(":").lower()
>
> There are a few standard library modules that encourage chaining of
>   side-effect calls (pstat comes to mind).  There shouldn't be any new
>   ones; pstat slipped through my filter when it was weak.