# Insert at first position of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, insert

How can I insert an element at the first index of a list?
If I use `list.insert(0, elem)`, does `elem` modify the content of the first index?
Or do I have to create a new list with the first elem and then copy the old list inside this new one?

Comment: It's a duplicate of [What's the idiomatic syntax for prepending to a short python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8537916/2745495).

Answer (score 433, accepted):

Use `insert`:

```
In [1]: ls = [1,2,3]

In [2]: ls.insert(0, "new")

In [3]: ls
Out[3]: ['new', 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 38):

From the documentation:

> list.insert(i, x)
>   Insert an item at a given position. The first
>   argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so
>   `a.insert(0, x)` inserts at the front of the list, and `a.insert(len(a),x)` is
>   equivalent to `a.append(x)`

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists