# Appending Elements From Left/Start of List/Array

Tags: python-3.x

I came across appending elements to array from left. and it has two solution

Solution 1:

```
List = [2,3,4,5,6]
List.insert(0,1) # Using insert 
List = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Solution 2:

```
List = [2,3,4,5,6]
[1] + List # Concatenation of array
List = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I'm new to Python So please can any one explain the time complexity of both solution according to me both solution takes O(n) am I right or wrong?

Comment: a similar question has been asked here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939652/insert-at-first-position-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: The `some_list.insert(0, x)` form is the most common.

Whenever you see it though, it may be time to consider using a collections.deque instead of a list. Prepending to a deque runs in constant time. Prepending to a list runs in linear time.