# inserting a value in a 2d list - python 2.7

Tags: list, append, 2d

i have a list....

```
lst = [[45], [78], [264], [74], [67], [4756], [455], [465], [4567], [4566]]
```

and i want to **add** a zero at the beginning so it looks like this....

```
lst = [[0], [45], [78], [264], [74], [67], [4756], [455], [465], [4567], [4566]]
```

This doesn't work...

```
lst[0] = [0]
```

or This...

```
lst.append(0,[0])
```

what will actually work?

cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537916/whats-the-idiomatic-syntax-for-prepending-to-a-short-python-list to prepend to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name goes, append always adds at the end. You need to do this:

```
lst.insert(0, [0])
```

in stead of lst.append(0,[0])