# How to insert an element at the beginning of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and the first one is having additional data (102) when compared to the second one.

**First List:**

```
['102 1 1 v-csm CSM vCSM enabled active up D:042 H:20 M:14 S:58 5.4.4.4-68.REL']
```

**Second List:**

```
['2  1 v-csm  CSM  vCSM  enabled active up  D:331 H:12 M:20 S:33  5.4.4.4-68.REL']
```

I want to insert a string like "xyz" at the first position of the list so that using pandas data can be mapped to correct columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the idiomatic syntax for prepending to a short python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537916/whats-the-idiomatic-syntax-for-prepending-to-a-short-python-list)

Answer (score 10):

Let's say that the second list is called `array`.

You can use `array.insert(0, "xyz")` or `array = ["xyz"] + array` to add "xyz" to the beginning of the second list.

Comment: This is list, so any way to add in the list itself at the beginning

Comment: @VishalMishra it is list , but as you show to us, this list only contain one string .