# Combine a simple value with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

[*What's the idiomatic syntax for prepending to a short python list?* is about modifying an existing list, and doesn't contain a suitable answer to this question. While a solution can be found in one its answers, it's not the best one.]

Is there a simple way to combine simple values and/or the elements of a list into a flat list?

For example, given

```
lst = [ 5, 6, 7 ]
x = 4
```

Is there a simple way to produce

```
result = [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

The following is satisfactory, but I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this:

```
result = [ x ]
result.extend(lst)
```

---

Perl:

```perl
my @array = ( 5, 6, 7 );
my $x = 4;
my @result = ( $x, @array );
```

JavaScript (ES6):

```js
let array = [ 5, 6, 7 ];
let x = 4;
let result = [ x, ...list ];
```

Comment: `y = [x] + list`

Comment: The closest analogue to the Perl and Javascript syntax in Python is `result = [x, *lst]` where `lst` is the other list.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; a meta-conversation about whether or not this question is a duplicate has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206935/discussion-on-question-by-ikegami-combine-a-simple-value-with-a-list).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can concatenate two lists (or two tuples).

```
result = [x] + lst
```

You could use the iterable unpacking operator on arbitrary iterables.

```
result = [x, *lst]
```

If you have a iterable you only want to make look flat rather than actually flattened, you can use `itertools.chain` to create an iterable generator.

```
import itertools
result = itertools.chain([x], lst)
```

---

If you're ok with prepending to the existing list instead of creating a new one, solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8537916/589924).

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed, you have the `+` operator to concatenate lists

```
[x] + [ 5, 6, 7 ]
# [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

---

You could also use the iterable unpacking operator:

```
l = [ 5, 6, 7 ]

[x, *l]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

---

Or you can also use `list.insert`:

```
l.insert(0, x) 

print(l)
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```