# python equivalent of javascript array destructuring

Tags: javascript, python

what's the python equivalent of the JS

```
const arrayWithMyNewItem = [mynewitem, ...existingarray]
```

Comment: `new_array = [item] + old_array`?

Comment: the above addresses the question but I did not see @NathanielFord expression which is actually what I was looking for

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892614/1659569 found it here

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the question as written is not the same as the question you meant to ask. That expression doesn't prepend to an array. Instead, it creates a new array constructed such that its items appear as they would have had you actually done a prepend on the original array.

Comment: It is a prepend, in that it puts the element on the front of the array. It's the idiomatic way in python, and while it creates a new array, that is also effectively true of javascript as well. O(n) where `n` is the size of the new list.

Comment: destructuring is called unpacking in python and uses a star for lists instead of 3 dots. i.e. ```arrayWithMyNewItem = [mynewitem, *existingarray]```

Comment: I renamed the question: @byteface thanks for that, I guess that's exactly what I was looking for